# How to print a double in C with absolute or relative error 10⁻⁶

Tags: c, math, output

I want to print a decimal number with error at most 10<sup>-6</sup>.
What does error at most 10<sup>-6</sup> mean?
E.g.: `10.35652383`,
Which of the following two options is correct?

```
1)10.356523 or 2)10.356524
```

As `printf("%.6lf")` prints with the decimal rounded off to 6 decimal places  `10.356524` will be printed.

Comment: Please tag with the language you wish to use, perhaps [c]. I am afraid your English is difficult to follow: do you mean you want to print an answer accurate to within 10^-6 (can’t do superscripts here :( )? When you say “with or without rounding off”, what do you mean: do you refer to some possibility of the language, or do you mean something you have to do by hand?

Comment: Do you (α) want code (as would be more usual here) to print a `double` (not a “decimal number”) or (β) asking which of two representations of 10·35652383 is ‘correct’ (as it sounds in your question)? Both representations satisfy have error < 10^-6, namely 0·00000083 or 0·00000017 respectively, so (β) is based on a false assumption. If you mean (α), are you asking how many places your need to print. By the way, a double cannot be exactly 10·35652383, as it is not M*2^N for integers M, N. Also `"%lf"` expects a `long double`, so `double d =10.35652383; printf("%.6lf", d)` is _might_ go wrong.

Comment: Meant “… asking how many places you need to print?”!

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate both absolute and relative errors:

```
x = 10.35652383
x1 = 10.356523
x2 = 10.356524

print "absolute error 1: {0}".format(abs(x1 - x))
print "absolute error 2: {0}".format(abs(x2 - x))

print "relative error 1: {0}".format(abs((x1 - x)/x))
print "relative error 2: {0}".format(abs((x2 - x)/x))
```

It gives:

```
absolute error 1: 8.30000001173e-07
absolute error 2: 1.69999999855e-07
relative error 1: 8.01427211289e-08
relative error 2: 1.64147741699e-08
```

So both absolute and relative errors are below 10e-6, i.e. below 0.000001, but the second value is closer.

Answer (score 0):

To print to the nearest `0.000001`, use `"%.6f"`

```
double x = 10.35652383;
printf("%.6f\n", x);
// or
printf("%.*f\n", 6, x);
// or drop .6, .6 is the default
printf("%f\n", x);

10.356524
```

To print to an approximate  `0.000001*x`, use `"%.6e"`

```
printf("%.6e\n", x);
// or
printf("%.*e\n", 6, x);
// or drop .6, .6 is the default
printf("%e\n", x);

1.035652e+01
```

Alternatively for relative precision: code could use the below when `fabs(x) < 1000000`.  It is unclear what is wanted when `x` is larger.

```
printf("%.*f\n", 6 - (int) log10((fabs(x)), x);

10.35652
```

The use of `l` as in `%lf` work the same as without it: `%f` for `printf()`.